# C++ finding the (largest) index of the largest element in an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an array of values and a technique for finding the index of the largest element in an array.

```
value = distance(arrayOfValues, max_element(arrayOfValues, arrayOfValues + N));
```

However if there's multiple instances of the largest value, for e.g. {3,1,3,4,4,3,2} it only returns the smallest index (in this case 3), whereas I'd like it to return the largest index, in this case 4.

The only way I can think of doing it would be to create a new array which is identical to 'arrayOfValues' but in reverse, and then apply the above method.

Is there a simpler way of doing it that would avoid creating a new array? Perhaps by manipulating the above piece of code?

Comment: Use a `for` loop and update your position with: `if (arrayOfValues[i] == maxElement) { pos = i; }`.

Comment: Can you use C++11 `std::rbegin` and `std::rend`? ( http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rbegin )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a for loop add an if statement. Something like...

```
int indexToReturn = 0;
int indexValue = 0;
int newValue = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arrayCount; i++) {
    newValue = arrayOfValues[i];
    if (newValue >= indexValue) {
        indexToReturn = i;
        indexValue = newValue;
    }
// At the end of this loop the value you want is indexToReturn
}
```

Comment: Note that OP uses `std::max_element`, so you may provide the whole loop that OP didn't write.

Comment: @Jarod42 You don't need to initialize an integer, it is set at 0 when declared. The value (if there is any value in the array) is assigned in the if statement.

Comment: [Counter example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36997db67d733f68): you need an initialization.

Comment: @Jarod42 The for loop will not run if there are no values to pass in and a value will always be passed in if it is run even once. This is not a good comparison.

Comment: I persist to say that `indexToReturn` and `indexValue` are not initialized. `indexValue` is read before to be set.

Comment: @Jarod42 I'll edit my answer just because it is safer to initialize them as they are declared but again, it's not needed.

Comment: [Sample code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a4a7a9fb18463e3) exhibits the UB when the variables are not initialized. (I've just added uncalled `std::cout` in loop).

Answer (score 3):

You may provide a custom comparer to also compare address:

```
const int index =
    std::distance(std::begin(arrayOfValues),
        std::max_element(std::begin(arrayOfValues), std::end(arrayOfValues),
        [](const int& lhs, const int& rhs) {
            return std::make_tuple(lhs, &lhs)
            < std::make_tuple(rhs, &rhs);
        }
        ));
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/knURRp)

Answer (score 3):

Use reverse iterators into your range.

You pass `end` to the reverse iterator constructor to get the reverse begin, and begin to get the reverse end.

```
template<class It>
std::reverse_iterator<It> rit(It i){return {i};}

template<class C>
struct backwards_t {
  C c;
  auto end() {
    using std::begin;
    return rit(begin(c));
  }
  auto begin() {
    using std::end;
    return rit(end(c));
  }
};
template<class C>
backwards_t<C> backwards(C&&c){return {std::forward<C>(c)};}
```

is a C++14 way to do it.

```
auto yarra = backwards(array);
auto it = std::max_element(yarra.begin(), yarra.end());
```

this also lets you call `backwards` in a `for(:)` loop and iterate backwards.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have something like this:

```
int maxIdx = 0;  
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  if(a[maxIdx] > a[i])
    maxIdx = i;

return maxIdx;
```

You just need to add one character to if statement:

```
if(a[maxIdx] >= a[i])
  maxIdx = i;
```

Comment: Whereas the solution is good, comment is wrong as OP uses `std::max_element`.