# Get std::min_element and std::max_element to return iterator to last value?

Tags: c++

When using `std::min_element` and `std::max_element`, if more than one element in the range is the lowest/highest, the returned iterator points to the first such element. However I have need for it to point to the last such element. Without writing my own function or reversing the input data structure, how can I do this?

My input data structure is a C-style array such as `int data[N]` and C++11 or Boost are not available (not my choice..)

Comment: When using std::max_element and std::max_element?? typo

Comment: @Angew Could you give a code sample using C-style array? Thanks.

Comment: Related to [finding-the-largest-index-of-the-largest-element-in-an-array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713281/c-finding-the-largest-index-of-the-largest-element-in-an-array)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't have to write your own data structure, you can use [`std::reverse_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator):

```
typedef std::reverse_iterator<int*> Rev;
std::size_t idx = Rev(data) - std::max_element(Rev(data + N), Rev(data)) - 1;
```

[[Live example]](http://ideone.com/mqAgAu)

Or, if you want the pointer:

```
int *p = std::max_element(Rev(data + N), Rev(data)).base() - 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering only the last greatest element there's already [`std::minmax_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) , which returns:

> a pair consisting of an iterator to the smallest element as the first
>   element and an iterator to the greatest element as the second. Returns
>   std::make_pair(first, first) if the range is empty. If several
>   elements are equivalent to the smallest element, the iterator to the
>   first such element is returned. **If several elements are equivalent to
>   the largest element, the iterator to the last such element is
>   returned.**

Answer (score 0):

You may use your own predicates:

```
struct LessWithOrder
{
    bool operator () (const int& lhs, const int& rhs) {
        return lhs != rhs ? lhs < rhs : &lhs < &rhs;
    }
};

struct LessWithInvOrder
{
    bool operator () (const int& lhs, const int& rhs) {
        return lhs != rhs ? lhs < rhs : &lhs > &rhs;
    }
};
```

and then

```
it = std::min_element(data, data + N, LessWithInvOrder);
it = std::max_element(data, data + N, LessWithOrder);
```